# Hibernate: Table generator inserting negative primary keys in table

Tags: hibernate, primary-key, hibernate-5.x, id-generation

I am using Table Generator strategy for generating primary keys. Recently I upgraded to Hibernate 5 and i am getting issue of primary keys getting generated negative values.
Database: PostgreSQL 9.3, Hibernate 5.0.2

Here are my annotations look like.

```
@Id
@TableGenerator(name = "EMP_ID",
                table = "ID_GENERATOR",
                pkColumnName = "GEN_KEY",
                valueColumnName = "GEN_VALUE",
                pkColumnValue = "EMP_ID",
                allocationSize = 10,
                initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "EMP_ID")
@Column(name = "EMP_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private long empId;
```

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Have you tried allocationSize=1 ?

Comment: I did, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Check if GEN_VALUE in database is less than initialValue property in the entity class generate this issue, for example:

If the column value GEN_VALUE is 0 and initialValue is 1, it generates negative value. To Solve the issue, equal initialValue with GEN_VALUE.

Regards,