# Hibernate generates negative id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hello am back searching for help: when i INSERT datas into my H2 console databse, i get negative id Values and all my fields have the "NULL" value.

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "tcustomer")
 public class Customer implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "pk_sequence",sequenceName = "sequence_tcustomer", initialValue = 1000, allocationSize = 100)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk_sequence")
private Long uidpk;
```

Help me please Thks

Here is an image of my H2 console database :
[image: H2 DataBase]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [H2 Sequence is generating Negative No. in Column \[JPA Spring\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47896049/h2-sequence-is-generating-negative-no-in-column-jpa-spring)

Comment: i  have checked  my Sequences, none of them is duplicated.

Comment: 'this my properties into my application.yml      <br>       
                 hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 100,
                 hibernate.order_inserts: true,
                 hibernate.order_updates: true,
                 hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data: true,
                hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: true'

Comment: For the solutions review this url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172805/hibernate-table-generator-inserting-negative-primary-keys-in-table/66877645#66877645